# checkstyle doesn't work on linux eclipse luna

Tags: java, eclipse, installation, checkstyle

I'm running Eclipse Luna on Linux (CEL 5.5).  CheckStyle 6.5.0 installs without errors, but CheckStyle doesn't appear in Window->Preferences.  Any chance there's something I'm doing wrong or could fix?

It works on Windows.

Thanks!

Comment: do you have any relevant error in your log `{workspace_loc}/.metadata/.log ?

Comment: maybe the newest version doesnt work on luna and you have to change to eclipse mars m6?

Comment: @flafoux: Aha: CheckStyle requires 1.7 and I'm running 1.6.  Thanks, like an idiot I forgot about the log file.  I have 1.7 installed, just needed to make it the default. (My project requires 1.6 and I guess I went too far setting that up.)  Please feel free to post that as an answer to get the credit.

Comment: By 1.6 and 1.7 do you mean Java 6 and Java 7?

Comment: @k-den Yes, that's what I mean!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your log in `.metadata` directory, it should indicates a version problem 
(see comment below question)